# run python code on a folder of files at once

Tags: python, xml, directory

I have a script that extracts data elements from XML files. I would like to run this on a directory(folder) of XMLs rather than a single one. This is what I have so far:

```
from xml.dom import minidom
from datetime import *
import os
import glob

filename = glob.glob("*.xml")
f = open(filename)
for xml in f:
    print (xml)
    xmldoc = minidom.parse(xml)
    tcd = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("QualityMeasureDocument")[0]
    sport = activitiesElement.attributes["root"]
    sportName = sport.value
    print (sportName)
```

I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Python34/Scripts/process.py", line 7, in <module>
f = open(filename)
TypeError: invalid file: ['CMS9v2.xml', 'country_data.xml', 'test.xml']
activitiesElement = tcd.getElementsByTagName("id")[0]
```

It would be nice to make this into a function as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extract your current parsing to a function:

```
def parsefile (filename):
    f = open(filename) 
    for xml in f: 
        print (xml) 
        xmldoc = minidom.parse(xml) 
        tcd = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("QualityMeasureDocument")[0] 
        sport = activitiesElement.attributes["root"]
        sportName = sport.value 
        print (sportName)
```

Call it:

```
for file in glob.glob(*.xml):
    parsefile (file)
```

In general, all you need to change to make part of a python script a function is to indent it and add a line

```
def functionname (var1, var2... ):
```

Where var1 etc. are names defined earlier that it relies upon.

Comment: Now receiving this error:  `>>> 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python34/Scripts/process.py", line 25, in <module>
    parsefile (file)
  File "C:/Python34/Scripts/process.py", line 12, in parsefile
    xmldoc = minidom.parse(xml)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\xml\dom\minidom.py", line 1960, in parse
    return expatbuilder.parse(file)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\xml\dom\expatbuilder.py", line 910, in parse
    with open(file, 'rb') as fp:
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n'
>>> `

Answer (score 3):

`glob.glob` returns a list of filenames. You are treating a list as file. try it this way

```
filenames = glob.glob("*.xml")
for filename in filenames:
     f = open(filename)
     ...
```

Comment: @Kevin or may use `glob.iglob` if you want to pick and process files 1 by one.